# How to split a string at the first `/` (slash) and surround part of it in a `<span>`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, split, substring

I want to format this date: `<div id="date">23/05/2013</div>`.

First I want to split the string at the first `/` and have the rest in the next line. Next, I’d like to surround the first part in a `<span>` tag, as follows:

```
<div id="date">
<span>23</span>
05/2013</div>
```

> ```
> 23
> 05/2013
> ```

What I did:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="date">23/05/2013</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#date").text().substring(0, 2) + '<br />';
  });
</script>
```

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K3D6d/).

But this does not work. Can someone help me with jQuery?

Comment: Your fiddle not referenced with `jQuery` Here is updated http://jsfiddle.net/K3D6d/2/

Answer (score 385, accepted):

Using [**`split()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

**Snippet :**

```js
var data =$('#date').text();
var arr = data.split('/');
$("#date").html("<span>"+arr[0] + "</span></br>" + arr[1]+"/"+arr[2]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="date">23/05/2013</div>
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K3D6d/5/)

When you split this string `--->` `23/05/2013` on `/`

```
var myString = "23/05/2013";
var arr = myString.split('/');
```

you'll get an array of size `3`

```
arr[0] --> 23
arr[1] --> 05
arr[2] --> 2013
```

Comment: You can also shorten the script like this: `var arr = $('#date').text().split('/');`

Comment: Thanks, Adil.  Your answer is worth to give one up. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using substring with a fixed index, you'd better use `replace` :

```
$("#date").html(function(t){
    return t.replace(/^([^\/]*\/)/, '<span>$1</span><br>')
});
```

One advantage is that it would still work if the first `/` is at a different position.

Another advantage of this construct is that it would be extensible to more than one elements, for example to all those implementing a class, just by changing the selector.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/ay4k2/) (note that I had to select jQuery in the menu in the left part of jsfiddle's window)

Answer (score 2):

You should use html():

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K3D6d/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#date").html('<span>'+$("#date").text().substring(0, 2) + '</span><br />'+$("#date").text().substring(3));     
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```js
date.innerHTML= date.innerHTML.replace(/^(..)\//,'<span>$1</span></br>')
```

```html
<div id="date">23/05/2013</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = $('#date').text().split('/');
console.log(arr);
$("#date").html("<span>"+arr[0] + "</span></br>" + arr[1]+"/"+arr[2]);
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="date">23/05/2013</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<div id="date">23/05/2013</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var x = $("#date").text();
    x.text(x.substring(0, 2) + '<br />'+x.substring(3));     
});
</script>
```

Comment: this doesn't work. you are calling `.text` on `x` ? are you sure ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("div#date").text().trim().replace(/\W/g,'/');
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/KingRider/pen/VajdpO)

Look a regular expression
http://regexone.com/lesson/misc_meta_characters

enjoy us ;-)

Answer (score -2):

```
var str = "How are you doing today?";

var res = str.split(" ");
```

Here the variable "res" is kind of array.

You can also take this explicity by declaring it as

```
var res[]= str.split(" ");
```

Now you can access the individual words of the array.
Suppose you want to access the third element of the array you can use it by indexing array elements.

```
var FirstElement= res[0];
```

Now the variable FirstElement contains the value 'How'