# get decimal places and convert it to whole number javascript

Tags: javascript

is it possible to get the decimal places only and convert it to whole number??

```
var Decimal = 1.25;
```

i want to get only the .25 and convert it to whole number so it will be like

```
25
```

is that possible??

I tried searching on the net it seems that i cant any answer to my question so i tried to ask here

i just need to get the decimal places and convert it to whole number again basically make it an int data type

any idea on how to solve my problem?

Comment: try using split method in jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711504/how-to-split-the-string-using-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hjfnaLaL/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to go through text:

```
var value = 1.25;
var fractionalPartAsWholeNumber = +String(value).split(".")[1];
```

That's fairly dense, but basically:

- `String(value)` gives us a string `"1.25"`
- `.split(".")` gives us an array with `"1"` in the first entry and `"25"` in the second
- `[1]` accesses the second entry in the array
- The `+` at the very beginning converts that back to a number — assuming you want it as a number, that is; if you want it as a string, leave that leading `+` off

If the values **always** have two digits of precision, you can do it mathematically:

```
var value = 1.25;
var fractionalPartAsWholeNumber = (value - Math.floor(value)) * 100;
```

Or you could convert to string, find out how many places there are to the right of the `.`, and then do the above but multiplying by 10^places. But the string method is probably fine.