# Jquery search date

Tags: jquery, html

I try search by date from directory tree.
But date is in file creation date is in filename and I want search between startDate and endDate.

[image]

My HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div style="float:left; width:17%;">
    <input type="text" style="height:37px;" id="startDate" class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YY">
</div> 
<div style="float:left; width:17%; margin:0 1%;">
    <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" style="width:97.71px;" id="endDate" height:37px;" class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YY" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button style="padding: 7.5px 12px; left:-1px;" class="btn btn-default" id="DateSearch" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:
Didn't figure out how to do it.
I found some datePickers but I dont want use them and found dataTables.
I want search in my directory tree by file creation date what is in filename.

Comment: You will have to get the file names first and then search --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994212/is-there-a-way-to-return-a-list-of-all-the-image-file-names-from-a-folder-using

Comment: `$.get('<?php echo index::get('baseurl')?>'+ajaxcall, function(data) {
            $('#dir-links').html(data);
            $('#dir-links-backup').html(data);
            bindTreeLinks(post_action);
    });` with this im getting all filenames to directory tree. My default search working well but I dont know how to make date search.. @Tasos

Comment: Get the filenames, iterate one by one and split with  (___) then with (#) and then (-). That should give you the date of the file name. eg (18) (02) (2016)  From then on you need to campare with your chosen dates. I suggest to use the example in the above link to get the filesnames and iterate through them. Then check here on how to split  -- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp  -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711504/how-to-split-the-string-using-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: I think splitting isn't hardest work what to do. I want know how I can search between two dates or something.

Comment: You do that by comparing -- I do a demo for you

Comment: Okay :) This will be nice of you :) @Tasos

Comment: There you go, i simplified it using (new date) to get the mili seconds and compare -- https://jsfiddle.net/3x9ozpbL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split as i mentioned in my Comments to make `year-month-date` in this format and compare each file date with your `from - to` range

example

**Html**

```
<p class="date">2013-08-4</p>
<p class="date">2014-09-5</p>
<p class="date">2015-09-5</p>
<p class="date">2016-09-5</p>
```

**Code**

```
    $(function() {
  var from = new Date("2013-09-4").getTime();
  var to = new Date("2014-09-8").getTime();

  $(".date").each(function(index, value) {
    var dates = $(this).text();

    if (from <= new Date(dates).getTime() && to >= new Date(dates).getTime()) {

      $(this).css("color", "blue");

    }

  });

});
```

**Output**

[image]

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/62mty9an/)

You could do the same in PHP using `strtotime($the_date);` which gives you minutes

Comment: You should probably stick the to and from `Date(from).getTime()` in vars outside the loop, so you don't work it out every time. (Not important, but would be quicker and might make that large IF easier to read)

Comment: @DBS  -- yeah that's a point -- i know it, but forgot it :)) cheers