# i have a input field with number and text split only number how

Tags: php, jquery

I have a input field with number and text , i want to split only number and use it for next actions how to do ?

```html
<input type="text" value="remain 24" name="none">
```

i need only 24 from value remain 24

Comment: are you wanting to split the string "remain 24" by the space? so you can access the number by itself?

Comment: use regex everything can be done with regex :))

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711504/how-to-split-the-string-using-jquery-or-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use regex to get only numbers from the string.

1. First get the value from that input, and it will be a string

   var inputVal = $('input').val();
2. `var extractedNum = inputVal.match(/\d+/)[0];`

Answer (score 1):

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/gpob920e/)

html:

```
<input id="txtInput" type="text" value="remain 24" name="none">
```

Jquery :

```
var Number = $("#txtInput").val().split(' ')[1];
alert(Number);
```

Also you can use Regex.

```
Number  = $("#txtInput").val().match(/\d+/);
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/gpob920e/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text"  value="remain 24" name="none">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var yourTxt = $('input').val();
        var number = yourTxt.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        $('input').val(number);
    });
</script>
```