# How to fill 2 text boxes by changing dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio

I have tried to fill 2 text boxes when a DropdownList changed.

 

The text in text box 1 is Name of ID_1.

The text in text box 2 is Age of ID_1

And if I choose another choices in the dropdownlist, the text in text box 1 and text 2 will be changed.

**For example,**

```
+----+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| Dropdownlist   | TextBox1     | TextBox2     | 
+----------------+--------------+--------------+
| 1              | John         | 23           |
+----------------+--------------+--------------+
| 2              | Vivian       | 43           |
+----------------+--------------+--------------+
```

**This is my database.**

```
+----+-----------+--------------+
| id | Name      | Age          | 
+----+-----------+--------------+
| 1  | John      | 23           |
+----+-----------+--------------+
| 2  | Vivian    | 43           |
+----+-----------+--------------+
```

**My code from .aspx**

```js
$('#<%:DropDownA.ClientID%>').change(function () {
  changeData();
});

function changeData() {
  var txt1 = $('#<%:DropDownA.ClientID%>').val();
  var txt2 = $('#<%:DropDownA.ClientID%>').val();
  $('input[id="TextBox1"]').val(txt1);
  $('input[id="TextBox2"]').val(txt2);
};

changeData();
```

```html
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownA" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" DataSourceID="SqlDataFromDatabase" DataTextField="id" DataValueField="name"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataFromDatabase" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:asrsDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [table]"></asp:SqlDataSource>


<input class="form-control" id="TextBox1" value="xxxx" type="text" style="color: green;" disabled>
<input class="form-control" id="TextBox2" value="xxxx" type="text" style="color: green;" disabled>
```

Thank you in advance for giving me the solution or suggestion.

> **The Solution.**
>   
>   ** Please follow this link for checking how to split the data: **
>   
>   [How to split the string using jQuery or JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711504/how-to-split-the-string-using-jquery-or-javascript)

```js
$('#<%:DropDownA.ClientID%>').change(function () {
  changeData();
});

function changeData() {
  var data1 = $('#<%:DropDownA.ClientID%>').val();
  var arr = data1.split(';');
  $('input[id="TextBox1"]').val(arr[0]);
  $('input[id="TextBox2"]').val(arr[1]);
};

changeData();
```

```html
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownA" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" DataSourceID="SqlDataFromDatabase" DataTextField="id" DataValueField="name"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataFromDatabase" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:asrsDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="Select (Name + ';' + Age) NameAge, id from [table]"></asp:SqlDataSource>


<input class="form-control" id="TextBox1" value="xxxx" type="text" style="color: green;" disabled>
<input class="form-control" id="TextBox2" value="xxxx" type="text" style="color: green;" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution #1: Drop-Down List Value

This solution would require you to store the pertinent information in the Value & Key attributes of the Drop Down List.  So your SQL statement would need to look like this: `Select (Name + ';' + age) NameAge, Id from [table]`

With this SQL Statement, you could then change your DropDownList `DataValueField` field to `NameAge` and split the key-value pair on `SelectIndexChanged` event to fill the two associated TextBoxe, when the `PostBack` occurs

#### Solution #2: Hidden reference values

Less ideal but will depend on your situation.

Basically, you have a Hidden Input field that holds ALL possible meta-data for the DropDown List and based on selection the pertinent information is extracted for further use in other locations.  Think of this like a Flat-file style storage mechanism.

This solution usually will require [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)/[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) to perform, as the data would generally be stored as [json](/questions/tagged/json).  Although, you could do a hierarchical CSV type design.

Comment: The solution #1 is worked !! . Thank you for the solutions and suggestion. I will edit my post then add my worked code :)